# How to get sum of a column containing $ characters in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I don't know if the SAME question has been asked before, I have a datagridview with columns in it, I want to get the sum of a column when I click a button and show the result in a label, but the column has values containing character '$'. Example: 700$. How can i do it?

Comment: Might need more information, but I would use the data source behind the datagridview to calculate the value, and use something like <Collection>.Count(o=>x.contains('$')) to get the number?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String amount = "";
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
 {
    amount = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(); //adjust column yourself
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(amount.Replace(@"$", ""));
 }
```

Comment: : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'